# await in async task method with synchronous logic c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've a stupid question to ask everyone to learn some best practises async return types in c#. I've a method like this:

```
        public virtual async Task OnConnected(WebSocket socket, HttpContext context)
        {
            string connectionId = CreateConnectionId(context);

            ConnectionManager.AddSocket(connectionId, socket);

            //Question is here await what ?

        }
```

I'd like to post to improve my application with a best performance with async and await. Pls don't thumb dowm my post. Can everyone suggest for me some resources best practices async return types?

Tks everyone.

Comment: "*Question is here await what*" nothing, you have nothing to await here (that you have shown), as it stands this method doesn't need to return a `Task` or be `async`. Also, asking us not to downvote is an open invitation to downvote

Comment: does your method have some implementation asynchrounour or calling any methods are work async ?

Comment: @ Ehsan Sajjad: my method have no logic async and this method is override from base class has async modifier

Comment: Perhaps a little reading would do :) [Async Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Even though you said not to thump down, but a question like this proves you haven't done any research on async-await and waiting for someone to feed it to you. The creator of C#, MS has their very own help just for you.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

or may be https://medium.com/@deep_blue_day/long-story-short-async-await-best-practices-in-net-1f39d7d84050

Comment: @ Michael Randall: my method have no logic async and this method is override from base class has async modifier and IDE warning this method has to have async modifier. Should I await Task.Delay(0) or await Task.CompletedTask, Is it ok ?

Comment: tks all so much

Comment: @ brainless coder : I've already researched from some best practices but I've no more experiences about this and I'd like to post to ask somebody to help me and I'm very happy. Btw tks for your helps and your resources

Answer (score 4):

If there is nothing to `await` and this is an overridden method. Just ignore the compiler warning (or `pragma` is out), and do nothing.

Why do nothing?

Because when you place an `async` on a method, the compiler automatically places any exception on the task for you.

or you could remove the `async` and return a *completed task*

```
public virtual Task OnConnected(WebSocket socket, HttpContext context)
{
   string connectionId = CreateConnectionId(context);

   ConnectionManager.AddSocket(connectionId, socket);

   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

My advice would be to do the former, (do nothing)

However if you were to go the second approach it would be better to place any exceptions on the *returned task* just as the *async and await pattern* would.

```
public virtual  Task OnConnected(WebSocket socket, HttpContext context)
{
   try
   {
      string connectionId = CreateConnectionId(context);

      ConnectionManager.AddSocket(connectionId, socket);

      // more stuff

      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return Task.FromException(e);
   }   
}
```

Comment: I remember that has in this link : https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns said that anti pattern is try catch without await. Is it ok for this case

Comment: @KhanhTuong if the method isn't `async` then you cant `await`. However in the second example we are marking sure we are placing any exceptions on the task in the same manner the *async and await pattern* would.. Once again, if you are unsure in this case, just do nothing

Answer (score 3):

> learn some best practises async return types in c#.

The first rule of `async` is "don't use it unless you need to." The second rule is "start with `await`, not `async`".

So this part of the question is incorrect:

> //Question is here await what ?

Instead of starting with `async` and trying to "make the code asynchronous", you should start at the opposite end: identify what is *naturally* asynchronous (i.e., what you should `await`) first. You need something to `await` *before* making your code asynchronous.

You *should* use `await` if you have naturally-asynchronous work to do. This is usually I/O-based, so if you're calling an API or doing a database query, that would be something that can be made asynchronous. Once you identified the low-level I/O call, change the method to call the asynchronous version of that API, and add an `await`. The compiler will guide you from there, changing the method containing the `await` to be `async` and changing its return type from `void` to `Task` or `T` to `Task<T>`. Then [let `async`/`await` grow naturally through your codebase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any asynchronous operation to be waited for, then you can make the method as a normal synchronous method. If you are making a method async, then it is good practice to name the method in such a way that it ends with ASYNC like OnConnectedAsync.

Generally you use async/await methods when you have any I/O operations (like file access, web download/upload) that can be done independent of your program logic. Simply put the control flow goes like,

1. main thread calls the async method to trigger the I/O operation
2. control is returned to main thread after an await is encountered; usually another thread is allotted to execute remaining statements of the async method
3. main thread continues to execute its statements until it requires the result of the I/O operation
4. main thread waits for the result of async method (i.e. result of I/O operation) by calling any wait or GetResult method of Task
5. once the main thread gets the results, it continues executing its statements

You can go through numerous tutorial videos on youtube on async/await.